# Special-Num DrScheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to make a function named special-num that takes in a list and then for every element in the list, divide it by 2 and round up.

Here is my code so far:

```
(define empty? '())
(define (special-num lyst)
  (cond((empty? lyst) lyst)
       ;((empty? (cdr lyst)) (ceiling (/ (car lyst) 2)))
       (else (list (ceiling (/ (special-num (car (cdr lyst))) 2))))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not redefine `empty?`, in the first line you're saying that is an empty list and two lines below you're using it as a predicate. Also, that's not the way we build an output list, use `cons`. And the way you're advancing the recursion is incorrect - better try this:

```
(define (special-num lyst)
  (cond ((empty? lyst) lyst)
        (else (cons (ceiling (/ (car lyst) 2))
                    (special-num (cdr lyst))))))
```